# Keeping static data in Android

Tags: android, database, android-fragments, storage

I have simple app: on pressed button it's show data about dog/cat in format  name / age / breed
I use two `fragment` and `eventbus` library to set communication beetwen them
`fragment` that send data in other fragment when button pressed is pretty simple

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class DogFragment extends Fragment{
        public DogFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dog_activity, container, false);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,view);

            return view;
        }

    @OnClick({R.id.dog1,R.id.dog2,R.id.dog3})
    public void setViewOnClickEvent(View view) {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.dog1:
                bus.post(new SendTextEvent(getResources().getString(R.string.Dog1),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.Two),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.Husky)));
                break;
            case R.id.dog2:
                bus.post(new SendTextEvent(getResources().getString(R.string.Dog2),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.One),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.Malamute)));
                break;
            case R.id.dog3:
                bus.post(new SendTextEvent(getResources().getString(R.string.Dog1),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.One),
                        getResources().getString(R.string.Samoyed)));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

fragment that accept and show data for user

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus;
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class InformationFragment extends Fragment {

    private  TextView nameText,ageText,breedText;

    EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();

    @Override
   public void onStart(){
       super.onStart();
   }


    public InformationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.information_layout, container, false);
         ButterKnife.bind(this,view);
             bus.register(this);
         nameText=  view.findViewById(R.id.name);
         ageText = view.findViewById(R.id.age);
         breedText = view.findViewById(R.id.breed);

        return view;
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(SendTextEvent event) {
        nameText.setText(event.nameText);
        ageText.setText(event.ageText);
        breedText.setText(event.BreedText);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
       bus.unregister(this);
        super.onDetach();
    }


}
```

Constructor for data that will be send by eventbus

```
public class SendTextEvent {

    public String nameText;
    public String ageText;
    public String BreedText;

    public SendTextEvent(String setName,String setAge, String setBreed) {
        this.nameText = setName;
        this.ageText = setAge;
        this.BreedText = setBreed;
    }
}
```

res-values

```
<string name="One">1</string>
<string name="Two">2</string>
<string name="Dog1">Dog1</string>
<string name="Dog2">Dog2</string>
<string name="Dog3">Dog3</string>
<string name="Husky">husky</string>
<string name="Samoyed">samoyed</string>
<string name="Malamute">Malamute</string>
```

when it’s simple and has 3 “dogs” with 3 characteristics it’s looks nice.
But for example, if  I want to create 50 buttons for  30  “dogs” and 20 cats  with 20 characteristics for every dog/cat like height,weight, eyes color e.t.c  it will be stupid to wright all this manually in values and it will not be looking good in code

So my question is  :
How can I store static data  in format name /age / breed /  height/ weight e.t.c   that will be preloaded when app created , then  I can retrieve it and send  it beetwen fragments when specific button is pressed ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `SingleTon` class may help you

Comment: @TaseerAhmad looks good. But what if i want to add localization for that data? Should i jusr create alternative SingleTon  with localized datat and use him when Android Locale change? Or there other ways?

Comment: You have to manually provide [localization](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization) in your resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a json file in `assets` folder structured like this:
`{
  "dogs": [
    {
      "name": "dog1",
      "age": 1,
      "characteristic": "husky"
    },
    {
      "name": "dog2",
      "age": 3,
      "characteristic": "husky"
    },
    ...,
    {
      "name": "dog30",
      "age": 3,
      "characteristic": "husky"
    }
  ],
  "cats": [
    {
      "name": "cat1",
      "age": 1,
      "characteristic": "british"
    },
    {
      "name": "cat2",
      "age": 2,
      "characteristic": "short hair"
    },
    ...,
    {
      "name": "cat20",
      "age": 2,
      "characteristic": "short hair"
    }
  ]
}`

And read this json file while the app opening. To read you can see [this tutorial.](https://tutorialsha.com/json-file-from-assets-folder-into-a-listview-with-example-android/)

Comment: Thanks! Keeping data in json are fitted perfectly!